# Is it normal for manual DNS queries on a CentOS server to not return authoritative section details?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, centos, nslookup

CentOS 5.7

On occasion when I'm performing manual DNS queries from one of my CentOS servers, I'll get results back that don't include an authoritative section.  For example:

```
[root@foobox ~]# nslookup -q=mx foo2.org 8.8.4.4
Server:         8.8.4.4
Address:        8.8.4.4#53

Non-authoritative answer:
foo2.org       mail exchanger = 10 mail.messaging.microsoft.com.

Authoritative answers can be found from:

[root@foobox ~]# nslookup -q=mx foo2.org  216.170.153.146
Server:         216.170.153.146
Address:        216.170.153.146#53

Non-authoritative answer:
foo2.org       mail exchanger = 10 mail.messaging.microsoft.com.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
foo2.org       nameserver = ns61.worldnic.com.
foo2.org       nameserver = ns60.worldnic.com.
ns61.worldnic.com       internet address = 205.178.190.31
ns60.worldnic.com       internet address = 206.188.198.30
```

It that normal? If programs are issuing queries and can't find authoritative answers, will that prevent them from trusting the non-authoritative answer they're given?

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is normal.  It is a good thing.  It basically just means you got results from the cache instead of from the authoritative servers for a particular zone.

Everything should be fine.  The only reason you get a notice about it within nslookup, is because nslookup is mostly used as a troubleshooting tool, and knowing you are getting cached data is often important to understanding why you got the result that you got.

Comment: So just to be clear, if I DO see output in the "Authoritative answers can be found from:", that means the results above that are cached? ...and when I DON'T see output in the "Authoritative answers can be found from:", that means that my DNS query pulled the latest record from the authoritative source?